# Selecting xml node by attribute id

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml2js

My aim is simple, I just need to get the value by an attrbiute. For example consider this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<preferences>
    <custom-preferences>
        <staging>
             <preference preference-id="foo">true</preference>
             <preference preference-id="bar">true</preference>
        </staging>
    <custom-preferences>
<preferences>
</xml>
```

The xml is in a file, this is what I have so far:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
xml2js = require('xml2js');
 
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(pref, function(err, data) {parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {

    console.log(result.preferences['custom-preferences'][0].staging[0].preference[0]);

    });
});
```

So if I hard code the index it will work, but can I select the node where preference-id = foo or bar etc.

I'm trying to avoid reading the parent node and performing a for each. I am happy and willing to use other package or libraries if it will help me to achieve the goal.

Comment: "Select ... in xml", i (intuitively) think: xpath! [document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) or [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Code by node.js

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const response = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<preferences>
    <custom-preferences>
        <staging>
             <preference preference-id="foo">true</preference>
             <preference preference-id="bar">true</preference>
        </staging>
    </custom-preferences>
</preferences>`

const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(response);
console.log('foo: '   + dom.window.document.querySelector('[preference-id="foo"]').textContent)
console.log('bar: '   + dom.window.document.querySelector('[preference-id="bar"]').textContent)
```

Result

```
$ node find-attribute.js
foo: true
bar: true
```

Code by Python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
document = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<preferences>
    <custom-preferences>
        <staging>
             <preference preference-id="foo">true</preference>
             <preference preference-id="bar">true</preference>
        </staging>
    </custom-preferences>
</preferences>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(document)
print("preference-id='foo' " + root.find(".//*[@preference-id='foo']").text)
print("preference-id='bar' " + root.find(".//*[@preference-id='bar']").text)
```

Result

```
$ python find-attribute.py
preference-id='foo' true
preference-id='bar' true
```